# Derive Fourier transform of $\sin x$ without using exponentials

Tags: calculus, integration

When deriving the fourier transform of $\sin(x)$ using the definition of the fourier transform

$$\int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(t)e^{-jwt} dt\ = \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(t)(\cos(wt)-j\sin(wt) dt\ = 0 -j\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(t)\sin(wt) dt = \begin{cases}
0 & : w\neq1\\
-j\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \sin^2(t) dt & : \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
$$-j\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \sin^2(t) dt = -j\left[ \frac{t}{2}-\frac{\sin(2t)}{4} \right]_{-\infty}^\infty = \text{diverges}$$
This does not equal $ \dfrac{\pi}{i}[ \delta(\omega - 2 \pi A)-\delta(\omega + 2 \pi A)] $. How do you go from this integral to the fourier transform of $\sin(x)$ without using the euler identity?

Comment: Consider using by parts twice